# Jquery - Run a function if an element's value is "Active"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with a class `reflection`. When the document is loaded, I set the value for that element to `disabled`. I want to then run a function only if the value is set to `active`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reflection").val("Disabled");

  $(".reflection").click(function () {
    $(".reflection").val("Active");
  });

  if ($(".reflection").val("Active") {
    if(e.clientX < width / 2) {
      croquis.fillLayerRect(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)], (e.clientX + (2 * (width/2 - e.clientX))), e.clientY, brush.getSize(), brush.getSize());
    }
    else {
      croquis.fillLayerRect(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)], (e.clientX - (2 * (e.clientX - width/2))), e.clientY, brush.getSize(), brush.getSize());
    }
  }
});
```

When I refresh the browser, the `if($(".reflection").val("Active")` function is immediately activated. The function works even though I set the value to `disabled`. I didn't click on `.relection` either.

Comment: Why can't you just have the html have Disabled in its class at the start?

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is wrong (not just the missing closing brace):

```
if ($(".reflection").val("Active")) {
```

It actually sets the value to "Active", and **the whole condition always evaluates to true**. because the `val()` method returns the original element object, which is truthy, and which is why your code in the if statement always get executed, along with unwanted setting the value to "Active".

You need this:

```
if ($(".reflection").val() === "Active") {
```

Comment: Buttons really don't have values, which is what he's using. Instead you should be checking to see if his button has the disabled attribute.

Comment: @slime I've never seen the HTML, just pointing out what's wrong with the code in general / addressing the issues that OP has shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only trigger on page load, since the check you do for active is not triggered by anything else.

If you instead try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reflection").val("Disabled");

  $(".reflection").click(function () {
    $(".reflection").val("Active");
    $(document).trigger('customTrigger');
  });


  $(document).on('customTrigger ready', function() {
    if ($(".reflection").val() == 'Active') {
      if(e.clientX < width / 2) {
        croquis.fillLayerRect(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)], (e.clientX + (2 * (width/2 - e.clientX))), e.clientY, brush.getSize(), brush.getSize());
      }
      else {
        croquis.fillLayerRect(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)], (e.clientX - (2 * (e.clientX - width/2))), e.clientY, brush.getSize(), brush.getSize());
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Then the check will trigger when document is ready, and also when `.reflection` is clicked.

Edit: I'm guessing the button is a `<input type="button">`, because the `<button>` element does not have value attribute.